# How to print variable values instead of memory allocation in python

Tags: python

I have coded a class that stores a name string and an int ratings ("John", 6) and stored it in a list "teams = []"

```
class player():
    def __init__(self, name, rating):
        self.name = name
        self.rating = rating

teams = []

teams.append(player("juanma", 6))
teams.append(player("pablo", 7))
teams.append(player("gon", 5))
teams.append(player("pep", 4))
```

I have then used the combinations tool from itertools and I am trying to get it to print all the possible combinations. The problem is that it is printing the memory allocation instead of the variables.

```
comb = combinations(teams, 2)

for i in comb:
    print(i)
```

This is the output that I get:

```
(<__main__.player object at 0x7fc4999698b0>, <__main__.player object at 0x7fc499969610>)
(<__main__.player object at 0x7fc4999698b0>, <__main__.player object at 0x7fc499999e20>)
(<__main__.player object at 0x7fc4999698b0>, <__main__.player object at 0x7fc499a015e0>)
(<__main__.player object at 0x7fc499969610>, <__main__.player object at 0x7fc499999e20>)
(<__main__.player object at 0x7fc499969610>, <__main__.player object at 0x7fc499a015e0>)
(<__main__.player object at 0x7fc499999e20>, <__main__.player object at 0x7fc499a015e0>)
```

Comment: What were you expecting to see instead?  You haven't defined a `.__str__()` or `.__repr__()` method on your class to give it any particular string representation.

Answer (score 1):

YOU have to provide this.

```
class player():
    def __init__(self, name, rating):
        self.name = name
        self.rating = rating
    def __str__(self):
        return "<player {} {}>".format(self.name,self.rating)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define an [`__repr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) or [`__str__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) internal function for your `player` class:

```
class player():
    def __init__(self, name, rating):
        self.name = name
        self.rating = rating
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name # Or any other string representation
```

You can find a nice explanation of the difference between these two methods here: [What is the difference between __str__ and __repr__?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/what-is-the-difference-between-str-and-repr)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `.__str__()` method on your class:

```py
def __str__(self):
  return "Name: " + self.name + " Rating: " + str(self.rating)
```